# Fix broken external Links?

Tags: html, mod-rewrite, shopware

I just noticed this:
All partner links have this structure:

```
https://www.webseite.de/shop/?sPartner=77.77.77777
https://www.webseite.de/shop/?sPartner=666666666
```

The links given to the partners look like this:

```
https://www.webseite.de/shop/default/?sPartner=77.77.77777
https://www.webseite.de/shop/default/?sPartner=666666666
```

The only thing that occurs to me is that the problem could possibly be corrected using modrewrite via the htacces.
Do you have any ideas how the problem can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewite the incorrect url to the correct one using htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

## Rule ##
RewriteRule ^shop/default/?$ shop/ [L]
```

Comment: Hello, im sorry für this replay but i need a little bit help. Again.
My new Config is now:
mywebsite.de (without "shop")

I see some Partnerlinks in my database like this:
https://www.mywebsite.de/default/?sPartner=490123015
The number is random
Now i have to trim like this:
https://www.mywebsite.de/?sPartner=490123015
but i dont know how i can let the number untouched
https://www.mywebsite.de/default/?sPartner=2342552432
https://www.mywebsite.de/default/?sPartner=543543515
https://www.mywebsite.de/default/?sPartner=490654565

Sorry

Comment: maybe this, seems working: RewriteRule ^default/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: @Dr.JoeBeer The backreference would not seem necessary... `RewriteRule ^default/$ / [R=301,L]` would be sufficient based on your examples. (The `RewriteCond` directives are not required either.)

Comment: @Dr.JoeBeer You want to rewrite mywebsite.de/default/?sPartnet={number} to mywebsite.de/?sPartner={number} right?
You can use this `RewriteRule ^default/$ / [R=301,L]` as @MrWhite said